# Increase font-size on higher resolutions

Tags: css, height, screen-resolution

I have a website 960px in width with little content, when viewed on resolutions  over 1400 > there is too much white space. I want to increase font-size on some elements so it fills the empty height on higher resolutions. How can I achieve this without making it responsive?

Thanks.

Comment: Just use media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries are a great option, but you may also want to try using EM or %. Both of these are relative values depending on screen size or PPI. Generally you can start from 0.8em for your `<p>` tag and go from there.

You can also try to fiddle around with line-heights but I am unsure of how exactly you could differentiate them without media queries.

**EXAMPLE**

```
p {
    font-size: 0.8em; 
    line-height:1.2;
}
```

Comment: I'm using a fixed footer layout with a container around it. Unfortunately that makes it difficult to make it responsive. It fits perfectly on 1400x900 just resolutions higher than that shows too much white. I have used the following but it doesnt work.

@media only screen and (min-device-height: 900px)
{.main p{font-size:18px;}}

I assume i'd have to use a bit of jquery to target the height of .main div so it increases the font-size for paragraph?

Comment: Hmm, sorry I don't think I understand. You shouldn't need to use jquery to change font-sizes. Could you possible create a jsfiddle with your css and html for an example and I'll try my best to help!

Comment: @7O07Y7 See my example above